# Android ARM Instructions

Tags: android, arm

1) How to create app using ARM instruction for android like media player etc?
2) Can we learn ARM Instructions using Emulator in Android ?
Please guide me in this where to start any tutorialsThanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624350/provide-help-for-using-android-ndk ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't need to use ARM instructions (assembly level programming for ARM) to create applications like media player.
2. You can learn ARM instructions using via Android's Emulator ([QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/)). However there are other emulators as well.

Start with [Cortex™-A Series Programmer’s Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013c/index.html) if you would like to learn ARM instruction sets or programming for ARM (Cortext A) specific things in general.

If you would like to do native development (c/c++) in Android, you are going to use Android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

If you would like to do Android application development like media players, you are going to use Android [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

In simpler terms (reverse order of above); If you don't know where to start at Android development you should get SDK. If that's not enough for you because Java is slow (and you've checked [Render Script](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html)) or you need some kind of access which can't be done at Java level then you should look into NDK and if that's still not enough for you then you should go check ARM documents.

Comment: Thanks. When to use NDK or SDK to develop an application for device like Mobile or tablets.